# Is there a way to fix the width of a column using OpenXml Library in C#?

Tags: c#, openxml-sdk

I have a Word table with 2 columns.  I am trying to get Word not to squeeze column1 when column2 has long text that wraps.

here is the intended layout:

```
 column1   Column2                
 -------   -------                
 1.        Long text that wraps   
           a couple of times.     
           Another paragraph of   
           long text that wraps.  

 2.        More long text that    
           wraps again.           
           Also another paragraph 
           of long wrapping text.
```

Notice column2 has 2 paragraphs in each cell.  Not sure if this matters, but that's what has to be in there.

When the number of table rows reaches double digits and after I programmatically send the completed document to the browser on the client site (they see it as a download and open it in Word) this is what happens:

```
 column1   Column2                
 -------   -------                
 .         .
 .         .

 9.        Long text that wraps   
           a couple of times.     
           Another paragraph of   
           long text that wraps.  

 1         More long text that    
 0.         wraps again.           
           Also another paragraph 
           of long wrapping text. 

 1         More long text that    
 1.        wraps again.           
           Also another paragraph 
           of long wrapping text.
```

Notice how "10." and "11." in column1 get wrapped (because Word decided to squeeze the width of that column,...I think)

I tried increasing the GridColumn width (even to a large value) to no avail.  Word always seems to re-size the column widths to what it sees as the best fit...I think.  I read on other forums (not Microsoft websites) that all width settings are considered "preferred" only.  Not sure if this is true, but it seems true enough in this case!!

I have tried setting

```
new TableCellProperties()
{
  Width = "4000",
  Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Pct
}
```

also

```
{
  Width = "3170",
  Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa
}
```

I have also tried table layout set to fixed:

Type = TableLayoutValues.Fixed

Also set the table cell margins and the TableCellSpacing to 0 in the table properties; but nothing helped.

Is there any OpenXml API that tells Word not to mess with a column's width?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those interested, I finally resolved this.

The solution was to abandon the table object altogether.  Instead I relied on Paragraphs only.

There were several discussions on the internet that clearly mentioned that column-widths in a table object in Word cannot be accurately controlled through OpenXml.  I do not know for sure if this is true, but as I mentioned in my question above, nothing I tried helped.  Not even fixing the width in Word itself before extracting the code from it with OpenXml SDK tools.  No one offered a concrete alternative either.

But, using Paragraphs with Indentation and Justification objects and embedding a Tab character, separated the contents of the paragraph into 2 "columns," where the right column accurately wraps indented.  Giving me the exact desired result as in the table in the question above.  No squeezing of column1 either.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem but I was able to do it using the TableLayout property.

```
// First, we create the table, its properties and we append it.
Table table = new Table();
TableProperties props = new TableProperties();
table.AppendChild<TableProperties>(props);

// Now we create a new layout and make it "fixed".
TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(){ Type = TableLayoutValues.Fixed };
props.TableLayout = tl;

// Then we just create a new row and a few cells and we give them a width
var tr = new TableRow();
var tc1 = new TableCell();
var tc2 = new TableCell();
tc1.Append(new TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = "2000" }));
tc2.Append(new TableCellProperties(new TableCellWidth() { Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Dxa, Width = "2000" }));
table.Append(tr);
```

Now, when we add text to the table, this is no longer rescaled.

Comment: Thanks Miguel.  Although that was more than 2 years ago, I remember trying this approach, especially with Type = TableLayoutValues.Fixed.  It still did not help.  There must have been something else in the fray.  At any rate, my applied solution, though a little hacky, has been working fine.  No need to touch it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I used this code to adjust particular column's width, while all others column are automatically adjusted based on their content.

```
Table tbl = new Table();

TableProperties tableProp = new TableProperties();
TableStyle tableStyle = new TableStyle() { Val = "TableGrid" };

// Make the table width 100% of the page width.
TableWidth tableWidth = new TableWidth() { Width = "5000", Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Pct };

tableProp.Append(tableStyle, tableWidth);

tbl.AppendChild(tableProp);

//Add n columns to table
TableGrid tg = new TableGrid(new GridColumn(), new GridColumn());

tbl.AppendChild(tg);

TableRow tr1 = new TableRow();

//I Manually adjust width of the first column
TableCell tc1 = new TableCell(GenerateTableCellPropsWithWidth("270"), new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("№"))));

//All other column are adjusted based on their content
TableCell tc2 = new TableCell(GenerateTableCellPropsWithWidth(), new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Title"))));

tr1.Append(tc1, tc2);
tbl.AppendChild(tr1);

//This method is only used for headers, while regular rows cells contain no TableCellProperties
private TableCellProperties GenerateTableCellPropsWithWidth(string width = null)
{
    TableCellProperties tcp = new TableCellProperties();
    tcp.AppendChild(width.IsNullOrEmpty()
        ? new TableCellWidth {Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Auto}
        : new TableCellWidth {Type = TableWidthUnitValues.Pct, Width = width});
    return tcp;
}
```